# python matrix multiplication broadcast error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am trying to multiply 5 matrix's in same line and getting following error,

```sh
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-4809be28729a> in <module>
     95   u_prev = np.transpose(u[t-1, :]).reshape(-1,1)
     96 
---> 97   x[t] = np.mat(A)*np.mat(x_prev) + np.mat(B)*np.mat(u_prev) + np.mat(process_noise)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (9,1) into shape (9)
```

Here is the code snippet: There are multiple arrays A,B,x_prev, u_prev, random noise. Just need to multiply them together.

```py
A = np.matrix([[1, 0, 0, ts, 0, 0, 1/2*ts**2, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, ts, 0, 0, 1/2*ts**2, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ts, 0, 0, 1/2*ts**2],
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ts, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ts, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ts],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

B = np.zeros((9, 3))

# --- update the state
process_noise = 0 + np.sqrt(Q)*np.random.uniform(-1,1)
process_noise = np.transpose(np.matrix(process_noise))

t = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
u = np.zeros((len(t), 3))
x = np.zeros((len(t), 9))

for t in range(1,t.size):   
    u[0, :] = np.array([Fx, Fy, Fz]) # set initial input
    u[t, :] = np.array([Fx, Fy, Fz])
    x_prev = np.transpose(x[t-1, :]).reshape(-1,1)
    u_prev = np.transpose(u[t-1, :]).reshape(-1,1)
    x[t] = np.mat(A)*np.mat(x_prev) + np.mat(B)*np.mat(u_prev) + np.mat(process_noise)
```

I also tried `x[t] = A * x_prev + B * u_prev + process_noise` but get the same error.

Comment: The example code isn't minimal. Can you simplify it?

Comment: Stop using `np.mat` and `np.matrix`.  That forces things to be 2d.  Use `np.array` instead.  If you need matrix multiplication, use `np.dot` or the `@` operator (`np.matmul`).

Comment: The `x[t]` expression is wrong.  `x` is 2d; `t` is a float array.  It can't be used as an index.  Did you omit an iteration, `for i in range(len(t)):`?

Comment: @hpaulj I omit an iteration just to make code small.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Don't use `numpy.matrix`.

Comment: `x[0]` is shape (9,).  According to the error, the RHS is (9,1).  It can't put the (9,1) into the (9,).  `A` is (9,9), `x+prev` is (9,1) (even without the `np.mat), matrix product is then (9,1).   If `A` was a `ndarray`, and `x_prev` simply `x[t-1,:]`, their `dot` would be (9,9) with (9,) => (9,), and the assignment should work

Comment: @AMC :Here is the entire error message
` ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-4809be28729a> in <module>
     95   u_prev = np.transpose(u[t-1, :]).reshape(-1,1)
     96 
---> 97   x[t] = np.mat(A)*np.mat(x_prev) + np.mat(B)*np.mat(u_prev) + np.mat(process_noise)
     98 
     99   # update measurement

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (9,1) into shape (9)`

Comment: @JayPatel Add that to your post, it's practically unreadable otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct way to matrix multiply in a loop:

```
In [74]: A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)                                                                               
In [75]: x = np.zeros((3,3))                                                                                         
In [76]: y = np.ones((3,))                                                                                           
In [77]: x[0]                                                                                                        
Out[77]: array([0., 0., 0.])
In [78]: np.dot(A,y)                                                                                                 
Out[78]: array([ 3., 12., 21.])
In [79]: x[0] = np.dot(A,y)                                                                                          
In [80]: x                                                                                                           
Out[80]: 
array([[ 3., 12., 21.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

You are trying to do:

```
In [81]: y = np.ones((3,1))                                                                                          
In [82]: y                                                                                                           
Out[82]: 
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])
In [83]: np.dot(A,y)                                                                                                 
Out[83]: 
array([[ 3.],
       [12.],
       [21.]])
In [84]: x[0] = np.dot(A,y)                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-48dd32783c97> in <module>
----> 1 x[0] = np.dot(A,y)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)
In [85]: np.mat(A)*np.mat(y)                                                                                         
Out[85]: 
matrix([[ 3.],
        [12.],
        [21.]])
```